# Design a many-to-many table for scale

Tags: database-design, scalability, many-to-many

I am thinking about scaling issues with many-to-many join tables.

I have a constructed example as following:

- Many users have many wishlists.
- On every wishlist are many items.

If I scale this table to million of users the *wishlist_items* table 
will get very big:

- 1000000 users
- 100 wishlists for every user
- around 1000-10000 items on every wishlist (bad example, but you get the point)

Therefore table size for the join table will be:

```
users * wishlist_per_user * items_per_wishlist
```

I think this is a very common situation in RDBM design. I am afraid that this users * wishlist_per_user * items_per_wishlist relation will grow out of bound.

Are there any similar experiences with such big tables and how to query them fast? How would I design my tables to prepare for better scaling?

Comment: You could partition the junction table on some logical bounds, although if the table is well-designed and has appropriate statistics and indexes, you'd be surprised how big you can make it and still have efficient access.

Comment: To get meaningful answers you need to include the actual requirements not some construed example.

Comment: Is it really your intention that one wishlist can "belong to" multiple users? Not one user per wishlist?

Comment: Not to be nitpicking, but what you're doing is not many-to-many but rather one-to-many (one user, many wishlists; one wishlist, many items). Like @MaxVernon said, there are very powerful setups that will accommodate a huge number of records, but if you need specifics, please provide us with things like schema, what platform and version you're on, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think using separate wishlists for separate users will be your best option. It will be efficient and will not contain millions of rows.